# How to return the response status

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have connections to the database written in Angularjs

```
$http({
        url: '/api/v1.0/relations/status/' + angular.element('#username').val(),
        method: "GET"
    })
        .then(function (result) {
            ...
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            if(error=== 403) {
                $scope.divRelationship = false;
            }
        });
```

Try to retrieve the status code from the error, however, you cannot

```
angular.js:12587 GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1.0/relations/status/jonki97 403 ()
```

Receives such an error in the console. How can we remedy this?

Comment: As I know, the response depends on how server-side is written and good API allow you to get status code too (if it's necessary) and such things as `error: false` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The error object is actually a response object, which contains the property 'status'.

So your code would need to look like:

```
$http({
    url: '/api/v1.0/relations/status/' + angular.element('#username').val(),
    method: "GET"
})
    .then(function (result) {
        ...
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        if(error.status === 403) {
            $scope.divRelationship = false;
        }
    });
```

---

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#general-usage

Comment: Strange because it does not work. https://zapodaj.net/2512e46d5ee18.png.html https://zapodaj.net/7fe1bb13b359e.png.html